# Is a mosfet considered as a transconductance amplifer?

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, mosfet, amplifier

Is a mosfet considered as a transconductance amplifer because it converters input voltage into output current?

Answer (score 2):

A transconductance amplifier generates a current depending on an input voltage. A MOSFET in common-source configuration would show the behavior of a transconductance amplifier, a MOSFET in a source-follower configuration however would behave as a voltage source.

The MOSFET itself is usually modelled as a transconductance, but it does not constitute a whole amplifier. Nevertheless sometimes an "intrinsic gain" is attributed to a MOSFET to specify the gain that could be achieved if it was biased using an ideal current source. For this hypothetical application, the transistor is regarded as an amplifier.

Comment: Differentiating between the behaviour of the MOSFET in Common Source mode vs the source follower configuration cleared everything.

Answer (score -1):

As a device, the MOSFET has transconductance when it is in its saturation region.

An amplifier is a transistor (or group of transistors) with its components for polarization, source/load coupling, power supply, signal conditioning and filtering, etc. So the MOSFET alone is not an amplifier, it needs to be polarized in the appropriate region to be a trasconductance amplifier.

Answer (score -1):

YES, of course (as each transistor). In an amplifier circuit the voltage gain is determined by the transistors small-signal transconductance gm=d(Id)/d(VGS).

**EDIT/Comment**: Apparently, there is somebody who cannot agree with the above. Hopefully, the questioner is not confused because of the downvoting (see also my comments below).

Comment: And by the circuit configuration. It is improper to speak of an individual device as a transconductance amplifier without regard to the topology.

Comment: EJP - have you ever heard about an operational transconductance amplifier (OTA)? Is there, in principle, a difference between OTA and FET? Both are characterized by the transconductance gm! Perhaps you think that "voltage-in and voltage-out" is a requiement for an amplifier? This would be a misconception. Hence, perhaps you reconsider your downvoting?

Comment: I should like to take this opportunity to make the following general statement:
In some cases, questions may be not quite clear (not everybodys mother tongue is english) but mostly one can guess what the core of the question is. In this case, I am sure the questioner wants to learn if the MOSFET is a transconductance device (yes or no) - and it is NOT of primary concern if the MOSFET as a stand-alone device may be called „amplifier“. I am afraid, in the present case, the questioner will be confused because correct answers are downvoted by somebody.

Comment: And this is, certainly, not in the interest of the questioner and also not in the interest of this forum.